# Unrooted smartphone with changed IMEI on android

Tags: android, spoofing, imei

I'm developing an android project to control users access. I use IMEI number like user-login, because I need users can use only one device to access, but I'm worried about IMEI cloning. I'd want to implement a booted phone control to be sure IMEI is original.
Is it possible to have an android phone unrooted with IMEI changed?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use device's MAC address for a unique identifier. Use the codes below for getting MAC Adress:

```
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = manager.getConnectionInfo();
String uniqueId = info.getMacAddress();
```

Do not forget to add this permission to Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Android device Unique ID:

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                    Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

there is a good explanation for this in this blog

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Most MediaTek-based Android phones (excluding the ones from Nokia/HMD) have Engineering Menu accessible with `*#*#3646633#*#*` (`*#*#engmode#*#*`) or similar secret code, and this menu is working from the system/telephony context and has special RIL access which allows entering AT commands without rooting. And MediaTek chipsets are famous (or, should I say, notorious) for their `AT+EGMR` command which, besides other things, allows IMEI modification.

All of this can be done without rooting the smartphone itself, although some OEM models actually **do** require root privileges explicitly even for the engineering menu.